# how to fix sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In this noti_card_data my DB schema

```
  id      | date  |        cmd  |     mbrNo
--------------------------------------------
  1        2020-04-01      success    1
  2        2020-04-29      fail       -
```

I Want result

```
  id      | date  |        cmd  |     mbrNo
--------------------------------------------
  1        2020-04-01      success    1
```

But, sending a query like this results.

```
SELECT * FROM noti_card_data WHERE mbrNo = '1'  OR mbrNo = '-'  AND cmd ='success' 



 id      | date  |        cmd  |     mbrNo
--------------------------------------------
  1        2020-04-01      success    1
  2        2020-04-29      fail       -
```

How to fix my query?

Comment: The query you provided could not have produced the result you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3DBanHZZFpYMYUguCDUuMv/1).

```
SELECT * 
FROM noti_card_data 
WHERE (mbrNo = '1'
OR mbrNo = '-')
AND cmd ='success'
```

Output:

```
| id  | date       | cmd     | mbrNo |
| --- | ---------- | ------- | ----- |
| 1   | 2020-04-01 | success | 1     |
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM noti_card_data WHERE (mbrNo = '1'  OR mbrNo = '-')  AND cmd ='success'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
mbrNo = '1'  OR mbrNo = '-'
```

you can say

```
mbrNo IN ('1', '-')
```

Although those two expressions are identical, the change would have coincidentally fixed your problem.

The real "problem" is

```
a OR b AND c   means   a OR (b AND c)
```

but you wanted

```
                       (a OR b) AND c
```

See "precedence of operators".